# Maintain state of Checkboxes from Database

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, model-view-controller, telerik-grid

I have data bound in Telerik MVC Grid with checkboxes. How do I get the checkboxes ticked based on the data from database. ie In the controller , I have got two outputs from two LINQ queries as shown below :

```
All.Data = resourceActions.Actions
                    .Select(i => new { i.ActionName, i.ActionID })
                    .ToList();

Checked.Data = roleResourceActions.Actions
                    .Select(i => new { i.ActionName, i.ActionID })
                    .ToList();
```

From above, the first LINQ query gives all data, where ActionID is unique.
The second LINQ query gives only checked data, where ActionID is unique here too.

So both the output has got ActionID as common. the first output is displayed to the Telerik Grid with checkboxes.

And I need to get the checkboxes checked from the output of the second LINQ query ie checked ActionIDs.

HOW IS IT POSSIBLE as I am new to MVC and LINQ ?

Answer (score 0):

```
foreach(Actions x in All.Data)
{
 if( Checked.Data.Contain(x))
{
<input type="checkbox" checked="checked">
}
else
{
<input type="checkbox" >
}

}
```

you have to do this some like it

Comment: Hi....well I have bound the data and added new field "IsSelected" dynamically thru LINQ query. This si a string type returning whether checked or not. I need to get the checkboxes checked from the Telerik Grid based on this field "IsSelected", using jquery. This should be done after data is bound